# Refresh recycler view after copying sqlite database in room

Tags: android

I am using a room database to populate a RecyclerView. In the settings, the user can back up and restore the underlying sqlite database. Backup/restore is a simply copy mechanism like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54113968/restoring-room-database-from-a-local-backup-file-livedata-viewmodel-doesnt-ref).

I restore the database back into the location `getDatabasePath(MyDatabase.DB_NAME)`, which works totally fine. However, if the user leaves the Settings Activity, **the RecyclerView is not refreshed**.

I guess that I have to tell Room that the DB has changed. But how do I do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is simple, you can refresh the recyclerview with this form

Put on resumen state

```
public override fun onResum() {
            super.onResum()
         list.remove(position);
         recycler.removeViewAt(position);
         mAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(position);                 
         mAdapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(position, list.size());
        }
```

States
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can return a `LiveData` list from the Dao, say `LiveData<List<MyPoJo>>`, and [observe it](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata#observe_livedata_objects) it in your activity; inside this `observe()` `notifyDataSetChanged()` for your `RecyclerView`.

This will convey live change of data whenever the Room changes to the underlying list of the `LiveData`

You can also use [`DiffUtil`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/DiffUtil) if you've a big list of data so that when the  notifyDataSetChanged()`gets called, only the changes will take place in your`RecyclerView` adapter.

[Here's an example of using DiffUtil](https://medium.com/@iammert/using-diffutil-in-android-recyclerview-bdca8e4fbb00)

[And here is an answer that with sample code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58730425/updating-a-recyclerview-by-a-new-livedatalist-return-from-room-dynamically#answer-58731052)